# how do you bring in old messages to the cache for reaction roles pycord/discord.py?

Tags: python, json, discord.py, pycord

Im trying to make reaction roles for my bot but i cant have it running 24/7 so i store the reaction role message(s) in a json file so i can fetch the data that i need at any time even between restarts, the problem is it does not react to me reacting to the message that was sent before the restart i figured this was because it was out of the cache or something i found a few sources saying that i needed to fetch the messages but that doesnt work either here is the code:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def react(ctx, title, description, *args):
    if len(args) % 2 != 0:
        return

    fields = []
    for i in range(0, len(args), 2):
        role_id = int(args[i][3:-1])
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)
        emoji = args[i+1]
        fields.append(
            {
                'name': f'{emoji} {role}',
                'value': '',
                'inline': True
            },
        )
    message = await ctx.send(embed=makeembed(
    title=title,
    description=description,
    fields=fields,
    ))

    for i in range(0, len(args), 2):
        await message.add_reaction(args[i+1])

    reaction_messages = load_data('reaction_messages.json')
    set_value(reaction_messages, str(message.id), {
        'message_id': str(message.id),
        'channel_id': str(message.channel.id),
        'guild_id': str(message.guild.id),
        'roles': [
            {
                'role_id': int(args[i][3:-1]),
                'emoji': args[i+1]
            }
            for i in range(0, len(args), 2)
        ]
    })
    save_data(reaction_messages, 'reaction_messages.json')


# Reaction handling here...

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    reaction_messages = load_data('reaction_messages.json')
    for item in reaction_messages:
        message = get_value(reaction_messages,item)
        channel = bot.get_channel(int(message['channel_id']))
        await channel.fetch_message(int(message['message_id']))
```

also heres the json file:

```json
{"1124400465283665950": {"message_id": "1124400465283665950", "channel_id": "1122126932755087382", "guild_id": "1122126932000116746", "roles": [{"role_id": 1122127011738026085, "emoji": "\ud83d\udc80"}, {"role_id": 1122127049289646152, "emoji": "\ud83d\udc7f"}]}}
```

Comment: This might not be a direct answer to your question, but would [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) accomplish what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Why doesn’t fetching messages work? I think you are trying to say that you will get the reactions off of the message and apply roles from there so that whether or not your bot is on, roles will be assigned

Comment: yeah i found out about `on_raw_reaction_add` and i got it working now @moinierer3000